# Multiple functions with different sub-type functions

Tags: c#

I have a lot of functions that repeat the first parts. Sub-functions or parameters of functions are different from each other. I want this code to run fast and happen in fewer lines. How do you think I should proceed?

```
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.XData.XOffsetAngle1.getUid(), "[Simulator]", ((altitude_value - targetAltitude) * (1345) / 10000).ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.XData.XOffsetAngle2.getUid(), "[Simulator]", ((altitude_value - targetAltitude) * (1594) / 10000).ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.YData.YOffsetAngle1.getUid(), "[Simulator]", ((altitude_value - targetAltitude) * (1345) / 10000).ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.YData.YOffsetAngle2.getUid(), "[Simulator]", ((altitude_value - targetAltitude) * (1594) / 10000).ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.XData.XDynamicTOF_max.getUid(), "[Simulator]", TimeOfFlight.ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.YData.YDynamicTOF_max.getUid(), "[Simulator]", TimeOfFlight.ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_7.XData.XDynamicTOF_max.getUid(), "[Simulator]", TimeOfFlight.ToString());
Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_7.YData.YDynamicTOF_max.getUid(), "[Simulator]", TimeOfFlight.ToString());
```

I wrote the code repetitively like this, but I couldn't think of a way to make it shorter.

Comment: Not knowing what those methods do in particular makes this hard to answer. _Maybe_ there would be ways to streamline that code. But I do not _really_ see anything obvious apart from extracting a reference to `Utils_Obj.Sim` but that won't do _that much_. I'd expect the optimizer to optimize the string literals, so there is also not really a _need_ to go for a `const` for example... I'd write a convenience funtion for that altitude formula, but that's more about readability ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the only kind of "optimization" that I might do:

```
var query1 =
    from t in new[]
    {
        new { i = 1345, us = new [] { Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.XData.XOffsetAngle1.getUid(), Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.YData.YOffsetAngle1.getUid() }, },
        new { i = 1594, us = new [] { Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.XData.XOffsetAngle2.getUid(), Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.YData.YOffsetAngle2.getUid() }, },
    }
    from u in t.us
    select new { uid = u, value = ((altitude_value - targetAltitude) * t.i / 10000).ToString() };

var query2 =
    from u in new[]
    {
        Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.XData.XDynamicTOF_max.getUid(),
        Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_11.YData.YDynamicTOF_max.getUid(),
        Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_7.XData.XDynamicTOF_max.getUid(),
        Utils_Obj.Sim.fa_7.YData.YDynamicTOF_max.getUid(),
    }
    select new { uid = u, value = TimeOfFlight.ToString() };

foreach (var z in query1.Concat(query2))
    Utils_Obj.set_ElementValue(z.uid, "[Simulator]", z.value);
```

The only real advantage is that there is no repetition of any element.

It really just looks like an awful object model in the first place to do anything with. I'd reconsider your source data structure.

Comment: i have to use this program written from outside source. I am aware that it is bad, there is nothing I can do. Anyway, Thanks for the help